# Email content checking

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

I am doing automation testing. In our web application the employees get daily mail notification. what i need is ,to write test case to check the daily emails. The emails contents are the services that they have to provide(type of services,date,time etc).So i need to check the services displayed in emails are corresponding to that particular employee or not?

Comment: Since the participants on this site are not likely your users or your product manager, they cannot tell you what you need to test.

Answer (score -1):

Instead using Selenium, you can write it by C#, Java or another language. Below is the link for C#.

[C# sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119653/how-to-read-the-body-of-the-message-in-the-mail-retrieve-from-gmail-by-using-pop)

Comment: I need to check content  before sending. Is it possible?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11069)

Comment: Thanks @TESTasy for your feedback, but the reading email code quite popular, we can easily search for it. I just provide the idea, not the code :)

Comment: @GiA, yes you can, it depends how you write the code, but do you need to check content of every email ?

Comment: yes. i need to check content of every email

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean of "not using selenium". Could you clarify this please? As it stands, this answer is quite confusing and might be removed if we can't raise its quality level. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable feedback, I will pay attention next time.